# Hibernate Text Table giving me NumberFormatException

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I'm trying to import a CSV file using Hibernate, but it already gives me a NumberFormatException in the first row. This is my script:

```
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE TEXT TABLE TKONTAKTE(KNUMMER INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,KVORNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,KNACHNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,KSTRASSENUMMER VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,KPOSTLEITZAHLORT VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,KGEBURTSDATUM DATE,KNOTIZ LONGVARCHAR,KMAENNLICH CHAR(1) NOT NULL,KEMAIL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT SYS_CT_46 UNIQUE(KVORNAME,KNACHNAME))
SET TABLE TKONTAKTE SOURCE "Kontakte.csv;fs=\semi;ignore_first=true"
ALTER TABLE TKONTAKTE ALTER COLUMN KNUMMER RESTART WITH 1
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD ""
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET WRITE_DELAY 10
```

And this is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:testdb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">SA</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.shutdown">true</property>
      <property name="transaction.factory_class">
      org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
    </property>

    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping resource="net/gobbz/kontakte/model/Kontakt.hbm.xml" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

It throws the following error:

```
11:53:57,813  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:48 - SQL Warning: -98, SQLState: S1000
11:53:57,813  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:49 -  bad TEXT table source file - line number: 1 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Petra;Pichler;Kennedystr. 279;39055 Leifers;19.04.1988;;FALSCH;petra.pichler@gmail.com"
11:53:57,875 DEBUG SQL:346 - insert into tkontakte (kvorname, knachname, kstrasseNummer, kpostleitzahlOrt, kgeburtsdatum, knotiz, kmaennlich, kemail, knummer) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, null)
Hibernate: insert into tkontakte (kvorname, knachname, kstrasseNummer, kpostleitzahlOrt, kgeburtsdatum, knotiz, kmaennlich, kemail, knummer) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, null)
11:53:57,875  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:71 - SQL Error: -32, SQLState: S1000
11:53:57,875 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:72 - The table data is read only in statement [insert into tkontakte (kvorname, knachname, kstrasseNummer, kpostleitzahlOrt, kgeburtsdatum, knotiz, kmaennlich, kemail, knummer) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, null)]
11:53:57,875 ERROR TestKontakte:40 - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException could not insert: [net.gobbz.kontakte.model.Kontakt]
```

Here the Kontakt.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-mapping package="net.gobbz.kontakte.model">
  <class name="Kontakt" table="tkontakte">
    <id name="nummer" column="knummer">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <properties name="vornameNachname" unique="true">
        <property name="vorname" column="kvorname"
            type="string" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="nachname" column="knachname" 
            type="string" not-null="true"/>
    </properties>
    <property name="strasseNummer" column="kstrasseNummer" 
        type="string" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="postleitzahlOrt" column="kpostleitzahlOrt" 
        type="string" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="geburtsdatum" column="kgeburtsdatum" type="date"/>
    <property name="notiz" column="knotiz" type="text"/>
    <property name="maennlich" column="kmaennlich" type="yes_no" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="email" column="kemail" type="string" not-null="true"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you please share ```Kontakt.hbm.xml``` ? Seems like your table is in read-only mode.

Comment: Does ```testdb``` is readonly or have ```testdb.properties``` where it is defined as readonly ?

Comment: I don't know how I can control if testdb is readonly, but testdb.properties has readonly=false

Comment: Can you try the query with schema name infront of the table name tkontakte? and does this table have a primary key or non-nullable unique key? If not I suggest you to add primary keys instead.

Comment: How can I do that? It has a primary key

Answer (score 0):

Your table columns do not match the data in the first row of the DSV file.

- the value for the date column is not formatted correctly (1988-04-19)
- the text for the KMAENNLICH CHAR(1) column is FALSCH, which is too long

Change the type of the date column to varchar(8). Use the correct order for the columns. Only when the text source is correct and there is no exception thrown for the SET TABLE TKONTAKTE SOURCE statement, you can execute your update statement. It complains about the table being read only because the table has no valid text source.